# Trying to access (query) content from Mysql database on Godaddy from local machine using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to read a mysql database online hosted my a godaddy account from a local machine using c#.  I figured it was going to be a simple deal, because I was coding PHP to access and write to the database from my godaddy account and it works fine.  However, my c# code is giving me problems.

I keep getting this error message whenever I try to "open" the connection:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.*

I'm confused because my PHP code doesn't have any issues connecting so I know the server is running, the username is viable, the password is fine, and the table can be accessed.  I can also "ping" the server without issue.

The c# code is pretty simple.  At this point, I'm just trying to read information from the database using an ID Number, but I hope to extend this functionality in a more complex scenario, but for now I just want to see if I can pull strings from the database.

I have read up on this, and I only get examples showing how to modify the mysql server using Microsoft products, which is not what I want.  I'm not hosting the mysql server from my machine.  I'm running this from Godaddy.  I have checked my godaddy user privileges for this username and database, and they have "All Privileges" enabled.  Also, I have read that some computers need the Windows Firewall modified to run this c# utility I'm writing.  That's not going to work, because I want to publish this utility in the future without the end user needing to enable weird stuff on their Windows Firewall.

Any ideas?

```
        string queryString = @"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 44";    
        string connectionString = @"server=222.222.22.22;"+
                                    "database=database1;"+
                                    "user id=dbuserid;"+
                                    "password='password';"+
                                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"+
                                    "connection timeout=15";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sdfds = myReader["Column1"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception E2)
            {
                label1.Text = E2.ToString();
            }
         }
```

It always crashes at "connection.Open()" as expected.  Is there anything I can do on the Godaddy end that will allow me to read the database from the c# application?  Or is this entirely a firewall issue?  Can I program in some ports to bypass the firewall issue?

Comment: Just randomly tagging stuff is considered bad practice. This is clearly c# and not php. And from the message it is clearly sql and not mysql.

Comment: Please change your user_id instead of user id

Comment: Sean, it pertains because I was using PHP to access the database.  Perhaps someone with PHP and C# experience can chime in if they encountered a similar issue.

Comment: Sanjay, thanks for the underscore.  I checked with MSDN and they didn't need an underscore.  But I'll add it to try it out.

Comment: Sanjay, I used "user_id" and it gave me this error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'user_id'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add NuGet package MySql.Data by Oracle,https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data then use

```js
using MySql.Data.MySqlClinet;

and in your method:

using(MySqlConnection ... = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (MySqlCommand cmd ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the nuget add package cmd line, but it gave me this error:  

**error: Value cannot be null.
error: Parameter name: projectUniqueName**

Any help?

Comment: try this: "server=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;database=xxx" for connectionString   and nuGet:                      Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.9.9 from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data

Comment: I figured out the problem with the "error: Value cannot be null..."  turns out I needed to run this from Visual Studio (Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer, then find the option for NuGet, then browse tab, then search for MySQL.Data.  Download that.  It installs in the project without issue.)

Thanks Florida for the proper strings for the credentials.  I'm just running into that.

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Additional information: Authentication to host '222.222.22.22' for user 'username2' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'username2'@'cpe-23-249-99-169.socal.res.rr.com' (using password: YES)**

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error now.  The code looks good, but it's giving me some **'cpe-23-249-99-169.socal.res.rr.com'** address that I never used.  What does that mean?

Comment: I'm not sure about go Daddy, probably cannot access mysql remotely from localhost, which is what it looks like with rr.com (roadrunner?). You might want to enable remote access to go daddy, or create a new database with remote access allowed.

Comment: Florida, thanks for your help.  I found the problem.  In my Godaddy CPanel, there is a utility called Remote MySQL.  In order for remote machines to access the databases, you need to add your local IP address to the list.  If you want to add more than one in a single Access Host, you can use the % for a wildcard.  I'd assume that %.%.%.% would allow anyone to access the database, assuming they had the proper credentials.  Now I can "open" the connectionstate on my .net C# application I'm writing and access the contents of my database table as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the .NET Provider for SQL Server (System.Data.SqlClient namespace objects) to connect to MySQL. Instead, you'll need to use a [managed provider for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) or a MySQL ODBC driver and System.Data.Odbc ADO.NET objects.